# SprintBoot: getting whitelabel page error when trying to hit api in Springboot

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, rest

When trying to hit the endpoint http://localhost:8080/users the page is getting "WhiteLabel Error". Can anyone resolve this issue. these are the snapshots of the controller class and error.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `rest controller` indicates that you have to access to “/courses”, but in the screenshot your are accessing to “/users”.

Change it to:
http://localhost:8080/courses

Comment: getting the same error page after changing the endpoint